# How would you combine two jsonb objects in one select statement, with ids?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to jsonb manipulation on PostgresSQL. I have two tables on my database, one containing a json blob with ids for another table, nested into it:

```
Table A
id | content
1  | { oneKey: "something", params: {anotherKey: "something", tableBEntries: [1,2]}}
2  | { oneKey: "something2", params: {anotherKey: "something2", tableBEntries: [3]}}
...
```

```
Table B
id | content
1  | {someKeysB: "values", anotherKeyB: "values"}
2  | {someKeysB: "values2", anotherKeyB: "values2"}
3  | {someKeysB: "values3", anotherKeyB: "values3"}
```

I want to select entries from Table A, and combine them with table B, so that the result is something like:

```
Result
id | content
1  | { oneKey: "something", params: {anotherKey: "something", tableBEntries: [{someKeysB: "values", anotherKeyB: "values"}, {someKeysB: "values2", anotherKeyB: "values2"}]}}
2  | { oneKey: "something2", params: {anotherKey: "something2", tableBEntries: [{someKeysB: "values3", anotherKeyB: "values3"}]}}
```

But, I can't find a way of doing this, on a simple `select` statement...only got so far as to extract `tableBEntries`:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(tableA.content->'params'->'tableBEntries')
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=168b0e1bb84e148b37eeea1eebab68c5)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_set(content, ARRAY['params','tableBEntries'], agg)                         -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        jsonb_agg(b.content) AS agg                                                  -- 3
    FROM
        a,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(content -> 'params' -> 'tableBEntries') as entries -- 1
    JOIN                                                                             -- 2
        b ON entries.value::int = b.id
    GROUP BY a.id, a.content 
) s
```

1. Expands the array into one row each element
2. Join these elements against `id` from `b`
3. Group content of `b` for relevant a records
4. Replace the `tableBEntries` element with the aggregated b values